# Top of the Screen gets too big on small screens in AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, screen-size, avd-manager

The top of the screen becomes way too big when I use small screens in the AVD Manager. In bigger screens it is normal. (It is the small line above the Toolbar)
For the layout in activity-main and content-main I used "match-parent"
Do you have an idea what is happening there and how I can fix it.

Thanks alot
Fabian

[small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVjai.png)

[big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsutZ.png)

This is my code in content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
   android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
    app:fabMenu="@menu/menu2">


</io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I just found out that the screen is like this without the app too.
Maybe its a problem with the AVD-Manager and not the code.

[small screen with closed app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSDnQ.png)

[large screen with closed app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjx3t.png)

Comment: Can you please post the code

Comment: thank you, do you need more?